# Как вызвать метод map у массива и вернуть значение каждого из элементов?

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести лучшие фильмы выбранных режиссёров, которые хранятся в полях top_rated_film массива directors. Задача — создать новый массив topFilmsList, состоящий только из лучших фильмов режиссёров. Как вызвать метод map у массива directors и вернуть значение top_rated_film каждого из элементов?

```
const directorsList = document.querySelector('.directors');
const directorTemplate = document.querySelector('.director-template').content;
const directorsBestFilms = document.querySelector('.content__best-films');

const directors = [
  {
    name: 'Стивен Спилберг',
    career: 'Продюсер, Режиссер, Актер, Сценарист, Монтажер',
    films: 'https://datalens.yandex/vwlqd2afsifoq?f3d80b92-5f21-40fa-b8d8-7255e038d045=22260&c8e5e20f-9329-4545-8550-b096c5b41d16=producer',
    top_rated_film: 'Список Шиндлера'
  },
  {
    name: 'Кристофер Нолан',
    career: 'Сценарист, Продюсер, Режиссер, Оператор, Монтажер, Актер, Композитор',
    films: 'https://datalens.yandex/vwlqd2afsifoq?f3d80b92-5f21-40fa-b8d8-7255e038d045=41477&c8e5e20f-9329-4545-8550-b096c5b41d16=writer',
    top_rated_film: 'Начало'
  },
  {
    name: 'Виктор Шамиров',
    career: 'Режиссер, Сценарист, Актер, Продюсер, Монтажер',
    films: 'https://datalens.yandex/vwlqd2afsifoq?f3d80b92-5f21-40fa-b8d8-7255e038d045=558079&c8e5e20f-9329-4545-8550-b096c5b41d16=director',
    top_rated_film: 'Со мною вот что происходит'
  },
];

directors.forEach(function (element) {
  const directorElement = directorTemplate.cloneNode(true);

  directorElement.querySelector('.directors__name').textContent = element.name;
  directorElement.querySelector('.directors__description').textContent = element.career;
  directorElement.querySelector('.directors__films').href = element.films;

  directorsList.append(directorElement)
})

const topFilmsList = directors.map(function (element) {
  return // верните значение соответствующего поля здесь;
}); 

topFilmsList.forEach((function (element) {
  directorsBestFilms.textContent = directorsBestFilms.textContent + element + ', ';
}))
```

Comment: Вставьте код текстом

Comment: исправил на текстовый код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод map() создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива.

```
const topFilmsList = directors.map(function (element) { // <- element содержит при каждом проходе елемент массива directors и вы можете обращаться к нему
    return // верните значение соответствующего поля здесь;
});
```

Т.е.

```
const topFilmsList = directors.map(function (element) {
  return element.top_rated_film;
});
```

topFilmsList будет содержать массив только с фильмами.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map